# Is casting int pointer to float pointer legal if they have the same alignment?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, type-punning

Let's say that both `int` and `float` are 4-byte aligned. According to ISO C99 6.3.2.3 p.7:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a
>   pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting
>   pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior
>   is undefined.

According to this, the following code should not invoke UB:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 7;
    float *f = (float *) &i;
    exit(0);
}
```

I noticed that GCC is not always good at catching strict aliasing rules violation attempts but here in can correctly warn that dereferencing *f  *will* break will break strict-aliasing rules what is illegal according to 6.5 p. 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression
>   that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of
>       the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>       effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>       qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>       types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>       subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

```
$ gcc  -Wall -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 so1.c -Wcast-align
so1.c: In function ‘main’:
so1.c:7:2: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
so1.c:7:9: warning: unused variable ‘f’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

So does it mean that this code may invoke UB only when *f will be dereferenced and it's 100% correct in current shape?

**EDIT:**

One more thing - would this cast be also legal if float had a different size from int but alignment would still be the same for both types? I think yes because this is what C standard says but I don't understand why alignment is the most important here and not size. Why does alignment matters when converting pointers and only when dereferencing?

Comment: I believe it's UB because `float` matches none of the conditions in your list.  However, you can muck about with a union.  (Or just use `-fno-strict-aliasing` like a normal human being.)

Comment: But it's UB only to dereference *f?

Comment: Whoops, yeah.  What you've done is fine.  But dereferencing `f` is not OK.

Comment: @user1042840: Should only be UB if you access the value through `f`, yeah. Kinda pointless to have that pointer without dereferencing it though. :)

Comment: Cool, I just want to make sure I understand everything. One more thing - would this cast be also legal if float had a different size from int but alignment would still be the same for both types?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant OP appears to only copy the address of `i` and not the contents.  Why is _that_ UB?

Comment: @chux sorry, I was referring to the act of dereferencing.

Comment: @chux: exactly, that's my point - 6.3.2.3 p.7 doesn't mention dereferencing, but it says that if two pointers have different `alignment` if it's already an UB to convert one into each other, so in theory anything can happen on this stage even without dereferencing.

Comment: If 2 types have same alignment requirements, _casting_ is OK regardless of type sizes per "C99 6.3.2.3 p.7".  If types have different sizes, (yet same alignment requirements), pointer arithmetic is a problem as `float *f = (float *) &i;  &f[1]` may be UB.  The end result is the _casting_ of like aligned types will not cause the problem so much as the typical _next_ operations of de-referencing and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: There exist(ed) machine architectures where merely loading an unaligned address into a register meant to index memory would cause a hardware trap.

But I don't think any contemporary architecture has that limitation

Comment: @rep_movsd: Some systems may use a shorter representation for pointers which are known to be aligned on coarser boundaries.  For example, a compiler for a 64-bit platform whose process space would be limited to 16GB could have pointers to word-aligned objects be 32 bits even though `void*` was 64 bits.  If code held a lot of references to `int`-aligned objects, such a design could cut in half the amount of memory/cache needed to hold pointers, potentially offering a significant performance win.